# count schedule conflict across multiple schedule options R

Tags: r

I'm working on a project were I am evaluating multiple potential schedules to identify the schedule with the fewest number of conflicts.

I have a data.frame, with different schedules stored in different columns (schd_1, schd_2):

```
schedules <- data.frame(course   = rep(c("Course A", "Course B", "Course C"), each = 2),
                        timeslot = c("Time 1", "Time 2"),
                        schd_1   = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                        schd_2   = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
```

And I have a data.frame containing, course registrations

```
registration <- data.frame(student = rep(c("John", "Mary", "Matt"), each = 2),
                           course  = c("Course A", "Course B", "Course A", "Course C", "Course B", "Course A"))
```

I need to find the number of conflicts that each schedule produces. So I am looking for something like:

```
course     timeslot   schd_1 schd_2
Course A   Time 1      2      0
Course A   Time 2      0      0
Course B   Time 1      2      0
Course B   Time 2      0      0
Course C   Time 1      0      0
Course C   Time 2      0      0
```

where the number in each cells is the number of students who have a conflicting registration for the time period.

I could use a loop to evaluate each column individually, but that would take a really long time (the actual data has thousand of potential schedules) and I am wondering it there is a faster implementation.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please explain what is a conflict? and illustrate why course A, time 1, has 2 conflicts for schd_1?

Comment: It has two conflicts because John and Matt are both signed up for Course A and Course B, but both are offered during time slot 1. Students can only take one course per time slot. Does that make sense?

Comment: so if course A were offered in both Time 1 and Time 2, there would be no conflict because both John and Matt could take A in Time 2 and B in Time 1?